# ControllerAdvice not handling certain exceptions

Tags: java, exception, error-handling, jhipster, controller-advice

After a few days browsing i didn't find a solution so I thought i'd post.
Right away, sorry for my english.

I'm trying to get custom exceptions from a backend running in Java with Jhipster's stack of technology (Spring MVC, JPA, etc...) to my front-end. In a certain case i created custom exception, handled it with custom handlers i added in the ControllerAdvice generated by Jhipster, and everything's works fine.

In another case i am trying to catch the same exceptions, but the ControllerAdvice doesn't fire at all and I end up with an error I can't do nothing with on the frontend. With Jhipster's generated exceptions i get the same un-usable error.

**The controllerAdvice (generated by jhipster)**

```
@ControllerAdvice

public class ExceptionTranslator implements ProblemHandling, SecurityAdviceTrait {

    private static final String FIELD_ERRORS_KEY = "fieldErrors";
    private static final String MESSAGE_KEY = "message";
    private static final String PATH_KEY = "path";
    private static final String VIOLATIONS_KEY = "violations";

    @Value("${jhipster.clientApp.name}")
    private String applicationName;

......

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
    @ExceptionHandler(OdoLoginAlreadyUsedException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleLoginAlreadyUsed(OdoLoginAlreadyUsedException ex, NativeWebRequest request){
        ApiError apiError = new ApiError(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        apiError.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
        return buildResponseEntity(apiError, request);
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
    @ExceptionHandler(OdoEmailAlreadyUsedException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleEmailAlreadyUsed(OdoEmailAlreadyUsedException ex, NativeWebRequest request){
        ApiError apiError = new ApiError(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        apiError.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
        return buildResponseEntity(apiError, request);
    }

    private ResponseEntity<Object> buildResponseEntity(ApiError apiError, NativeWebRequest request) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(apiError, apiError.getStatus());
    }
```

**An example of the Exceptions**

```
public class OdoLoginAlreadyUsedException extends RuntimeException{
    public OdoLoginAlreadyUsedException(){
        super("Ce pseudo est déjà utilisé, veuillez ré-éssayer avec un pseudo différent.");
    }
}
```

**That works:**

***RestController***

```
@PostMapping("/register")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public ResponseEntity<AdvisorVM> registerAccount(@Valid @RequestBody AdvisorIn advisorIn)  {
    if (!checkPasswordLength(advisorIn.getPassword())) {
        throw new InvalidPasswordException();
    }
    advisorIn.setCreatedBy("Platform_Advisor");
    advisorIn.setCreatedDate(Instant.now());
    User user = userService.registerUser(advisorIn, advisorIn.getPassword()); ....
```

***Service***

```
public User registerUser(UserDTO userDTO, String password){
    userRepository.findOneByLogin(userDTO.getLogin().toLowerCase()).ifPresent(existingUser -> {
        boolean removed = removeNonActivatedUser(existingUser);
        if (!removed) {
            throw new OdoLoginAlreadyUsedException();
        }
    });
    userRepository.findOneByEmailIgnoreCase(userDTO.getEmail()).ifPresent(existingUser -> {
        boolean removed = removeNonActivatedUser(existingUser);
        if (!removed) {
            throw new OdoEmailAlreadyUsedException();
        }
    });
    User newUser = new User();
```

With this my ControllerAdvice catches the exceptions, build a response with the status and the error message i'm trying to get

**This does not**

***RestController***

```
 @PostMapping("/actions/ceUser")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole(\"" + AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN + "\")" + " ||hasRole(\"" + AuthoritiesConstants.ROLE_MANAGER + "\")")
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<String> createEditUser(@Valid @RequestBody CEUser ceUser) throws URISyntaxException, JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        User loggedUser = userService.getUserWithAuthorities().get();
        var userExtraGlobal=userExtraCustomService.findByUser(loggedUser).get();
        // User id is provided or not
        boolean createUser = (ceUser.getId() == null);

        if (createUser) log.debug("REST request to create User : {}", ceUser);
        else log.debug("REST request to update User : {}", ceUser.getFirstName() + " " + ceUser.getLastName());

        if (ceUser.getLogin() == null || ceUser.getLogin().isBlank()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("User login should not be null or blank");
        }

        if (createUser){
            if(userService.findOneByLogin(ceUser.getLogin().toLowerCase()).isPresent()) {
                throw new OdoLoginAlreadyUsedException();
            } if(userService.findOneByEmail(ceUser.getEmail()).isPresent()) {
                throw new OdoEmailAlreadyUsedException();
            }
        }
```

*Stack trace*

```
2021-03-15 12:02:37.593 ERROR 25372 --- [ XNIO-1 task-28] c.odonatech.odo360.web.rest.OdoResource  : Exception in createEditUser() with cause = 'NULL' and exception = 'Login name already used!'

com.odonatech.odo360.web.rest.errors.LoginAlreadyUsedException: Login name already used!
    at com.odonatech.odo360.web.rest.OdoResource.createEditUser(OdoResource.java:185)
    at com.odonatech.odo360.web.rest.OdoResource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2e8c9e4b.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    at com.odonatech.odo360.web.rest.OdoResource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$97daf673.createEditUser(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:523)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:155)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at com.odonatech.odo360.security.jwt.JWTFilter.doFilter(JWTFilter.java:38)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SessionRestoringHandler.handleRequest(SessionRestoringHandler.java:119)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)

2021-03-15 12:02:37.602  WARN 25372 --- [ XNIO-1 task-28] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [https://www.jhipster.tech/problem/login-already-used{400, Login name already used!, message=error.userexists, params=userManagement}]
```

With my custom Exceptions or Jhipster's built in exceptions, i get a 500 status on the front-side with an un-parsable json response, and i can't do anything with it.

I tried throwing my exceptions from my service instead of my RestController. I tried different annotations (EnableMVC for example) and other things I read but i have trouble pinpointing why it responds differently in the two situations.
I read things about filters may'be getting in the way of the ControllerAdvice? I don't know, if you guys could guide me in the right direction !

Thank you in advance

**EDIT**

There was an exception handler in the resource catching all the Runtime exceptions (which my custom exceptions extend), so it wasn't dispatched to the ControllerAdvice... ... anyway, thank you !

Comment: Some of the exceptions are handled by Zalando Problem library

Comment: Ok yes thank you it is imported and used by Jhipster in the ControllerAdvice. But weirdly, Jhipster's built in exceptions doesn't work either (the result is also a 500 with no useful infos, jhipster should normally build a "user friendly' error response and it sometime does) How could I get around this ?

Comment: Difficult to say, it's supposed to work. Maybe the default order of the different advices is wrong and you should explicit it. Try to learn more by running your app under debugger and if something is wrong in JHipster code, please report it on github.

Comment: Ok thanks i am gonna do that

Comment: There was an exception handler in the resource catching all the Runtime exceptions, so it wasn't dispatched to the ControllerAdvice... ... anyway, thank you !